# GnuPG Encryption without special characters

Tags: gnupg

I am using the below code to encrypt the text file. I need to read the encrypted text back and need to send in email. But for this its needs to be encoded without any special characters.

But When I encrypt using the below code, it is encrypting with special chracters.

```
gpg --output test.txt.gpg --encrypt --recipient test@test.com test.txt
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the "-a" (ASCII armor) argument to gpg:

```
gpg -a --output test.txt.gpg --encrypt --recipient test@test.com test.txt
```

This tells gpg to format it's output in base 64 encoding.

Sample:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: GnuPG v1
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=etE5
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```